# Don't know how to use toEnum in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Am pretty new in haskell. I have the following code piece:

```
data Weekdays = Mon | Tue | Wed | Thu | Fri | Sat | Sun
                deriving (Eq, Enum, Show)

weekday :: Date -> Weekdays
weekday date = toEnum (mod (cntDays date) 7)
```

I get the following error message:

```
Time.hs:8:29:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘Integer’
    In the first argument of ‘mod’, namely ‘(cntDays date)’
    In the first argument of ‘toEnum’, namely ‘(mod (cntDays date) 7)’
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

cntDays gives back an Integer. So how am I able to get back 'Sun' for example as a return Value wenn cntDays gives back a '6'?

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with `toEnum`. You need to convert number from `Integer` type to `Int` type. Use `fromIntegral`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is `cntDays` returns you an `Integer` while `toEnum` accepts only `Ints`

```
toEnum :: Enum a => Int -> a
```

You need to convert `Integer` to an `Int`. Use `fromIntegral` for it:

```
weekday :: Date -> Weekdays
weekday date = toEnum . fromIntegral $ (cntDays date) `mod` 7
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fromInteger` to turn an `Integer` into an `Int`, but you're probably better off just using an `Int` to begin with.